# R - Web Page Scraping - Trouble obtaining Attribute values using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to use rvest to pull ISO country info from wikipedia ( including links from another page ) . I can't find a way of correctly obtaining the links ( href attribute ) without including the name ( I have tried xpath string function it causes an error )  .  It is fairly easy to run - and self explanatory.

Any help appreciated!

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

searchPage <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2")
nodes <- html_node(searchPage, xpath = '(//h2[(span/@id = "Current_codes")]/following-sibling::table)[1]')
codes <- html_nodes(nodes, xpath = 'tr/td[1]/a/text()')
names <- html_nodes(nodes, xpath = 'tr/td[2]//a[@title]/text()')
#Following brings back data but attribute name as well
links <- html_nodes(nodes, xpath = 'tr/td[2]//a[@title]/@href')
#Following returns nothing
links2 <- html_nodes(nodes, xpath = 'tr/td[2]//a[@title]/@href/text()')
#Following Errors
links3 <- html_nodes(nodes, xpath = 'string(tr/td[2]//a[@title]/@href)')
#Following Errors
links4 <- sapply(nodes, function(x) { x %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("tr/td[2]//a[@title]") %>% html_attr("href") })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have included more info in your question. The "self-explanatory" 
bit nearly made me ignore the question (hint: consider providing sufficient verbal detail out of respect for others' time as well as broken code).

I say that b/c I have no idea if this is what you needed or not b/c you really didn't say.

```
library(rvest) 
library(tibble)

pg <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2")

tab <- html_node(pg, xpath=".//table[contains(., 'Zimbabwe')]")

iso_col <- html_nodes(tab, xpath=".//td[1]/a[contains(@href, 'ISO')]")
name_col <- html_nodes(tab, xpath=".//td[2]")

data_frame(
  iso2c = html_text(iso_col),
  iso2c_link = html_attr(iso_col, "href"),
  country_name = html_text(name_col),
  country_link = html_nodes(name_col, xpath=".//a[contains(@href, 'wiki')]") %>% html_attr("href")
)
## # A tibble: 249 x 4
##    iso2c          iso2c_link         country_name               country_link
##    <chr>               <chr>                <chr>                      <chr>
##  1    AD /wiki/ISO_3166-2:AD              Andorra              /wiki/Andorra
##  2    AE /wiki/ISO_3166-2:AE United Arab Emirates /wiki/United_Arab_Emirates
##  3    AF /wiki/ISO_3166-2:AF          Afghanistan          /wiki/Afghanistan
##  4    AG /wiki/ISO_3166-2:AG  Antigua and Barbuda  /wiki/Antigua_and_Barbuda
##  5    AI /wiki/ISO_3166-2:AI             Anguilla             /wiki/Anguilla
##  6    AL /wiki/ISO_3166-2:AL              Albania              /wiki/Albania
##  7    AM /wiki/ISO_3166-2:AM              Armenia              /wiki/Armenia
##  8    AO /wiki/ISO_3166-2:AO               Angola               /wiki/Angola
##  9    AQ /wiki/ISO_3166-2:AQ           Antarctica           /wiki/Antarctica
## 10    AR /wiki/ISO_3166-2:AR            Argentina            /wiki/Argentina
## # ... with 239 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks!   Sorry , I thought the comments would be good enough , will try to put more info in future!